# Unable to join Docker swarm because control.sock is missing?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have an existing Docker swarm consisting of three machines. I am trying to add a new manager to this swarm. I run the command

`docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-<...> 192.168.200.200:2377`

After a while I get the error

`Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not connect to prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`

I view the daemon logs using `tail -f /var/log/messages | grep docker`, I see this:

`Mar 17 17:07:48 UAT-Blockchain dockerd: time="2021-03-17T17:07:48.575024542+08:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {/var/run/docker/swarm/control.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc= \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/docker/swarm/control.sock: connect: no such file or directory\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc`

A quick check shows that `/var/run/docker/swarm/control.sock` is indeed missing on this machine, but is present on the machines in the existing swarm.

What is this `control.sock`? How should I go about enabling/reinstating it on this current machine? Is this a problem of faulty installation?

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: same as previous comment

Comment: I have reinstalled entirely the os and docker. It worked but not idea why it was broken.